# How to find the nth character or digit in a string using REGEX in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to find nth occurence of a digit or character using regex in perl.

For example: If the string is:

```
$string = 'abdg2jj4jdh5jfj6'
```

i need to match the digit 5 which is the 3rd digit.

How can i do it with regex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
my $string = "abdg2jj4jdh5jfj6";
my @myArray = ($string =~ /(\d)/g);
print "$myArray[2]\n";
```

Output:

> 5

Comment: Without a transition variable: `my $nth = ($string =~ /(\d)/g)[2]`

Comment: @TLP - Yeah - I was going to go there but I wanted it to be more obvious as to what was happening. It also has the benefit of only having to run the regex once to get any digit afterward.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative to Brian Roachs answer would be to use a capturing group like this

```
$string =~ /^\D*\d\D*\d\D*(\d)/;
print $1;
```

means match from the start of the string 0 or more non-digits (`\D`) then a digit (`\d`), the same again and then the digit you want to have in brackets, so it would be stored in `$1`.

But you need a longer regex, so I would prefer his solution (+1).

Answer (score 1):

```
my $k = 2; # one less than N
my ($digit) = $string =~ /(?:\d.*?){$k}(\d)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I allowed to say "you don't need a regex"?

You can do it with `substr()`.

Comment: He wanted to find the nth *number* in a string. That's how `5` is the "3rd digit". You can't do that with `substr()`